# Inexact differential and integrating factors

Tags: partial-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I am playing around with the differential $\mathrm{d}F = (x^2+4xy)\,\mathrm{d}x + (y^4+x^2)\,\mathrm{d}y$. This is not an exact differential, as 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2+4xy)=4x$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(y^4+x^2)=2x\neq 4x.$$
The standard procedure is now to find an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$, such that the differential $\mathrm{d}G=\mu(x,y)(x^2+4xy)\,\mathrm{d}x + \mu(x,y)(y^4+x^2)\,\mathrm{d}y$ becomes exact. This means again that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}((x^2+4xy)\mu(x,y))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}((y^4+x^2)\mu(x,y)).$$
Now that last equation can be simplified by carrying out the derivatives as far as possible. I end up with
$$2x\mu(x,x)=(y^4+x^2)\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}-(x^2+4xy)\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}.$$

That same procedure in lots of cases leads to an equation that is solved by a simple ansatz, such as $\mu$ being a function of $x$ alone, or $y$ alone, or $x+y$ alone, or even a polynomial. 
However, I have now tried several ideas for an ansatz, but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your equation can hardly be solved even without exactness. Not all DE are easy to solve.

Comment: A solution is not required in the end. Only to make it exact and stop there...

Comment: Well if it's exact than you can integrate it